# VB6 Activex component can't create object

Tags: vb6, activex, sql-server-2000, windows-server-2000

I am making a few minor updates to a VB6 application. It runs on a windows 2000 server connected to a SQL Server 2000 Database.

I took a copy of the source code from the server updated it and complied it locally. My local machine is running windows 7 64x. I copied the .exe file back to the server and when I tried to run it I received the runtime error 49: Activex component can't create object. I know this error occurs when the application tries to open a connection to the database using RDO.

I can run the .exe fine from my local machine and my virtual pc which is running windows xp.

This application was previously working on the server and the changes I made were to the contents of a file it outputs so no new references would be needed.

These are the lines it is falling over on:

```
rdoEnvironments(0).CursorDriver = rdUseNone 
Set conDB = rdoEnvironments(0).OpenConnection("MRA", rdDriverNoPrompt, True)
```

Comment: Are you positive you are using RDO and not ADO?  This could be related to the Win7 SP1 compatibility breaks in many MDAC/DAC libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is RDO.

These are the lines it is falling over on.

rdoEnvironments(0).CursorDriver = rdUseNone
Set conDB = rdoEnvironments(0).OpenConnection("MRA", rdDriverNoPrompt, True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing some DLLs for RDO to work on the server, try this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195474 - How To Determine RDO Files Needed for Distribution of App

Answer (score 2):

I recently resolved the `Activex component can't create object` error as follows:

- Open your `.vbp` file for your VB6 project in a text editor.
- At the top of the file will be all the activex objects the project uses.  In my case, these were:

  ```
  Reference=*\G{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#2.0#0#C:\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb#OLE Automation
  Object={22D6F304-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95}#1.0#0; msdxm.ocx
  Reference=*\G{3F4DACA7-160D-11D2-A8E9-00104B365C9F}#5.5#0#C:\WINDOWS\system32\vbscript.dll\3#Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
  Reference=*\G{3D0758FA-4171-11D0-A747-00A0C91110C3}#a.0#0#C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbgwproc.dll#Debug Object for AddressOf Subclassing
  Object={248DD890-BB45-11CF-9ABC-0080C7E7B78D}#1.0#0; MSWINSCK.OCX
  Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; mscomctl.ocx
  Object={F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}#1.2#0; COMDLG32.OCX
  Object={3B7C8863-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}#1.2#0; RICHTX32.OCX
  ```
- Open regedit app.
- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then search for each class id above, such as {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
- Expect to find `Reference=` entries in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface and `Object=` entries in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID
- After each entry you'll notice there's a version like `#1.2`.  In my case I found the same version number listed in a `Version` key near where I found a match in the registry.  If the versions don't match, it may be worth registering the OCX or DLL file of the correct version.
- After finding each entry, you can click in the regedit tree and hit left arrow till you get back to the `Classes` branch, then search for the next entry.
- Most importantly, if you don't find an entry for the class id you searched for, that is most likely causing the `Activex component can't create object` error.

In my case, the missing class was `Reference=*\G{3D0758FA-4171-11D0-A747-00A0C91110C3}#a.0#0#C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbgwproc.dll#Debug Object for AddressOf Subclassing`.  This is a special class used when running VB6 apps in the debugger but it should not be distributed with the app or referenced in apps that are distributed.  I got VB to stop referencing dbgwproc.dll by opening `Project > <app name> Properties... > 'Make' tab` and deleting `DEBUGWINDOWPROC = 1` from `Conditional Compilation Arguments:`.  After rebuilding, no more error occurred.